# Regex "not followed by"

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a custom URL detector for filtering purposes but having a problem with non-url typos.

In english, two sentences separated by period should have a space, but in most cases, users fail to adhere to this rule.

I have to match URLs without the protocol prefix, basically just the domain name and the 2 or 3 character TLD. How do I exclude strings exceeding the 3 character rule for the TLD?

Examples:

```
youtube.com (should match)

something.This (fragment of a sentence. Should not match because "This" contains 4 chars.)
```

Note that these strings could be anywhere in the haystack (start, middle, end). My current regex is this:

```
.'((https?|ftp)://)?'         // Protocol (optional)
.'(www(\.|\%2[Ee]))?'         // www prefix (optional)
.'([a-zA-Z-]+(\.|\%2[Ee]))+'  // domain strings separated by dot
.'([a-zA-Z-]{2,3})'           // tld 2 or 3 chars (should not be followed by another alpha)
.'([/\?]\S*)*'                // subdirectory or GET (optional)
```

Comment: Why are you limiting tld to 2 or 3 chars? What about `museum` or `info`... What do you want when you have `something.it`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I want to modify your regex for that achievement then I'll go for adding a **positive lookahead** after tld checking:

```
((https?|ftp):\/\/)?(www(\.|\%2[Ee]))?([a-zA-Z-]+(\.|\%2[Ee]))+([a-zA-Z-]{2,3}(?=\W|\b))([\/\?]\S*)*
```

You can see here:

```
((https?|ftp)://)?         // Protocol (optional)
(www(\.|\%2[Ee]))?         // www prefix (optional)
([a-zA-Z-]+(\.|\%2[Ee]))+  // domain strings separated by dot
([a-zA-Z-]{2,3}(?=\W|\b))  // ... following a non-word character or a word boundary
([/\?]\S*)*                // sub directory or GET (optional)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/kQ3eP5)

Comment: I have recently learned about word boundaries thanks to you :)